# Why my mongodb Shell not getting started even after my mongodb server is running?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.4

I am not getting the right problem what might be making the mongodb shell not getting initiated.
Here is the gist of my log of MongoDB:  https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/c6f964060bc27014d25e22066ed5f292
I do not know why it is showing the Index Build 2% or 30%.
Kindly, suggest me what might I do to initiate my shell and starte performing. I am running out of time due to this delay. PLease suugest me.

Answer (score 1):

You have managed to kill your mongod middle of index build.

> found 2 interrupted index build(s) on datastalk.stalk

Build of first index ({ v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }) didn't take long. Second index ({ v: 2, unique: true, key: { EMAIL: 1.0 }, name: "EMAIL_1", ns: "datastalk.stalk" }) is taking longer.. And at point of 35%, system got access violation when reading memory address 0x0000005648530000

Do your machine have enough memory and memory DIMMs are good?

You can try to solve this problem with [wiredTiger](http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.6.0/command_line.html) command line tools. Use dump to get your data from database to file, re-create your mongodb instance (remove all files from dbpath OR point your dbpath to other directory and restart mongod) and then import data back to database (re-creating needed indexes)

Comment: My system have 28 GB  RAM.

Comment: My configuration includes 32 GB RAM where 4GB  is reserved for system usage.

Comment: Can you run memory test? Because access violation on memcpy is something what you don't want to see.

Comment: Sure I will run memory test once. But still I am doubtful whether the problem is due to the RAM.

Comment: @JafferWilson added wt tool information to answer